# How to style the bootstrap cards with single row and four columns on it

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my angular application I have created the bootstrap card to display some information.

But it is not reaching the design as what I am expecting ,I have tried many ways.

**component.html**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="card" id="dd" style="max-width: 800px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-3" >
                heading-1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>heading-1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>heading-3</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5>info-1</h5>
                                        <h5>info-1</h5>

               </div>
            </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**component.css**

```
body{
background-color: #2d3436;
background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #2d3436 0%, #000000 74%);
color:white;
}

.bs-example{
        margin: 20px;        
    }

   #dd{
    background-color: #2d3436;
background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #2d3436 0%, #000000 74%);
color:white;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;

   }
```

**I want to show the data as with in the row place the 4 headings(heading-1,heading-2..) in the single row
and under each heading place the info and one line under that with the border and also in next row place the other info under each heading.**

Can anyone please help me regarding this I am new to using the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="card" id="dd" style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <h5>Heading 1</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                //have some info here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <h5>Heading 2</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                //have some info here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <h5>Heading 3</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                //have some info here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <h5>Heading 4</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                //have some info here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks@F Klng  it is absolutely working for me.Now I want to make the headings(headings-1,2,3..)as tabs(links).and when we click on that particular tab the data (i.e info) will be come like info1.1,info 1.2,info 1.3 etc  (has to come horizontally as above)if the heading another data info it has to come another card(after above card)like info 1.11,info 1.12 etc(and it is continued same for other headings also)can you please help me for this.

Comment: If the answer I provided works for your initial question please mark it as the correct answer. I do not exactly get the second question

Answer (score 0):

Do you import the bootstrap CSS somewhere? You need to do this in order for the styling to go through. For example you can import it in your HTML file. Like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Or import it in your CSS file like so:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Comment: Yes I have included bootstrap in my application eventhough I am facing the problem  can you please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to close your div tags and have your heading included within. You are very close.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="card" id="dd" style="max-width: 800px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-4" >
                heading-1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div>heading-1</div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div>heading-3</div>

            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>info-1</h5>
                <h5>info-1</h5>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That html seemed to work for me. So the diff here is that i put a closing tag after the divs with the col class. Then I also put col-4 instead of 3 since you only have 3 items in the header.